# jQuery random failing objects without plugin?

Tags: jquery, random, for-loop, jquery-animate, setinterval

I'm creating a greeting card for the holidays and I would like some snowflakes to fall. I don't want to use a plugin to accomplish this. I've generated some code that random places a snowflake on the screen. I'm trying a for loop to random place up to 20 flakes on the screen at once. It seems to placing 20 instances of the snowflake at the same position. I would like it to be random.

// Snow Falling
    function fallingSnow() {

```
    var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
    $('#snowZone').prepend(snowflake);
    snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width());
    snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() + 5000);

    snowflake.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
    snowflake.animate({
        top: "500px",
        opacity : "0",

    }, snowSpd, "easeInCirc", function(){
        $(this).remove();
        fallingSnow();
    });

}
var timer = Math.floor(Math.random() +1000);

window.setInterval(function(){
    fallingSnow();
}, timer);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUZba/13/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the element, not all elements with it's class.

```js
function fallingSnow() {
  var snowflake = $('<div class="snowflakes"></div>');
  $('#site').prepend(snowflake);
  snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#site').width());
  snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 20) + 1000;

  snowflake.css({
    'left': snowX + 'px'
  });
  snowflake.animate({
    top: "200px", // height of area
    opacity: "0",

  }, snowSpd, function() {
    $(this).remove();
    fallingSnow();
  });
}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  fallingSnow();
}
```

```css
.snowflakes {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
}
#site {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="site"></div>
```

Comment: I updated my code, now two many objects are falling at the same time.

Comment: After awhile multiple objects start falling at the same time.

Comment: @NickRivers Remove the call to `fallingSnow()` that is within `fallingSnow()`

Comment: @KevinB Can you make it fiddle for this output i tried your example but for the snowCount is not used anywhere

Comment: And to add more flakes, just call the method more times. http://jsfiddle.net/JSPnz/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/JSPnz/2/

Comment: Awesome +100 Kevin for Providing fiddle. Thanks this what i want.